# $vuetify.rtl=true moves only the content inside the component to right but it doesn't work to replace the component to right?

Tags: vue.js

https://moeddami.github.io/nuxt-material-admin-demo/dashboard/

In the above link i want the sidebar component towards right when $vuetify.rtl is enabled.

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization

Comment: Iam using the above concept for applying rtl.

Comment: mounted() {
    this.$vuetify.rtl = true;
  }

Comment: Iam using the above code in my App.vue